# Registering a property sheet shell extension for Win10 and Win11 doesn't work for .arw file

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-11, shell-extensions

I wrote a property sheet shell extension to display metadata from a file.
It works perfectly for a new file type such as `.foobar`.
But when registering for the existing `.arw`, the property sheet shell extension is simply ignored.

This looks the same issue as this very old SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011698/property-sheet-handlers-on-windows-10 This question unfortunately has no good answer.

The code use for registration is the following:

const
FileExt   = '.foobar';          // '.arw'
FileClass = 'FoobarFile';       // 'ArwFile'
FileType  = 'File of foobar';   // 'File of arw'

```
procedure TMyDelphiPropSheetHandlerFactory.UpdateRegistry(ARegister: Boolean);
var
    Reg         : TRegistry;
    ClassID     : String;
    Res         : UInt;
    SubKey      : String;
begin
    ClassID     := GUIDToString(Class_MyDelphiPropSheetHandler);
    Reg         := TRegistry.Create;
    try
        if ARegister then begin
            inherited UpdateRegistry(ARegister);  // This registers the COM object as usual

            Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
            SubKey := FileExt;
            if not Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, TRUE) then begin
                MyMessageBox('Unable to open key "HKCR\%s"', [SubKey]);
                Exit;
            end;
            Reg.WriteString('', FileClass);
            Reg.CloseKey;

            SubKey := FileClass + '\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\' + ProgName;
            if not Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, TRUE) then begin
                MyMessageBox('Unable to open key "HKCR\%s"', [SubKey]);
                Exit;
            end;
            Reg.WriteString('', ClassID);
            Reg.CloseKey;

            Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
            SubKey := '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved';
            if not Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, FALSE) then begin
                MyMessageBox('Unable to open key "HKLM\%s"', [SubKey]);
                Exit;
            end;
            Reg.WriteString(ClassID, FileType);
        end
        else begin
            // Unregister
            Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
            SubKey := '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved';
            if Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, FALSE) then begin
                Reg.DeleteValue(ClassID);
                Reg.CloseKey;
            end;

            Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
            SubKey := FileClass + '\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers';
            if Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, TRUE) then begin
                Reg.DeleteKey(ProgName);
                Reg.CloseKey;
            end;

            SubKey := FileExt;
            if Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, FALSE) then begin
                Reg.DeleteValue('');
                Reg.CloseKey;
            end;
            
            inherited UpdateRegistry(ARegister);  // This unregister the COM object as usual
        end;
    finally
        Reg.CloseKey;
        Reg.Free;
    end;
end;
```

[image: .arw part 1/3] [image: .arw part 2/3] [image: .arw Part 3/3] [image: ArwFile Part 1/2] [image: ArwFile Part 2/2]

Comment: More information is required about how you registered the shell extension? What already existed in the registry for `.arw` and how does it look now?

Comment: I registered the shell property page extension as explained in Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts. This involve registering the COM object as usual and then linking it to the file extension. Remember: it works for .foobar file type but not for .arw. I updated my question with the registration I use.

Comment: Please include in your post the registry settings for `.arw` and for some `.foobar`. We need to see something...

Comment: I should add that the property sheet registration work nicely with Windows 7. Win10 and 11 have different behavior for which I did not found any description in Microsoft documentation.

Comment: FWIW, I have reproduced @fpiette's observations on Windows 7 (works) and Windows 10 and 11 (doesn't work); Even with all other shell extensions disabled for the .arw file type, the custom property sheet handler is not invoked for arw-files on Windows 10&11.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

I had to write a new key: `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations﻿\.arw\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers` and a subkey with my property sheet handler name having default value equal to his CLSID.

This is somewhat documented in [Microsoft documentation for "Association Arrays"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee872122(v=vs.85)).

I added the code below to the source code in my question:

```
    SubKey := 'SystemFileAssociations\' + FileExt;
    if Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, FALSE) then begin
        Reg.CloseKey;
        SubKey := SubKey + '\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\' + ProgName;
        if not Reg.OpenKey(SubKey, TRUE) then begin
            MyMessageBox('Unable to open key "HKCR\%s"', [SubKey]);
            Exit;
        end;
        Reg.WriteString('', ClassID);
        Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
```

Credit: I received Anders M. help to find the solution.